# Creating a KTOR HttpClient that only uses the cellular connection even if WiFi is connected inside a KMM mobile app

Tags: kotlin-multiplatform, ktor, ktor-client

I'm trying to create a KMM app that will work on Android and iPhone devices that have cell service as a requirement. The idea is that the network layer would use KTOR and manage 2 instances of HttpClient where one is making calls over the cellular network to the cloud and the other is making calls over WiFi knowing that the WiFi is connected to some custom hardware and does not have access to the cloud. These two instances could be used simultaneously so that the user does not have to toggle wifi back and forth between the hardware and the cloud.

I'm confused by some of the KTOR engine documentation I've seen that implies I can pass it a NetworkType, and also taken the angle of writing platform specific versions that configure the HttpClient differently per platform, but I don't seem to be getting any closer.

Can anybody point me in the right direction?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you know how to use only a cellular network on Android without using Ktor?